# Determining whether statement is Tautology or not with universal quantifiers and implication

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm not sure how to approach these two puzzles. The first one, I intuitively guess is a tautology as it's basically saying the same thing.

1. $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are both open sentences in single variables. Is
   $$(\exists x A(x)\land \exists xB(x)) \implies (\exists x)(A(x)\land B(x))$$ a tautology?

2. $A(x,y)$ is a two-variable open sentence. Is $$(\forall x)(\forall y)A(x,y)\implies (\forall x)A(x,x)$$ a tautology?

Comment: Assume $A$ is "x is odd" and $B$ is "x is even", then do you have first?

Comment: In the first , you have to write $\exists x \wedge \exists y$

Answer (score 2):

Well, the puzzle obviously tries to confuse you with the first statement. Because regarding the premise of the first implication the existence of $x$ such that $A(x)$ is true and the existence that $x$ exists such that $B(x)$ is true might suggest that we talk about the same object. The thing is, we do **not**. We simply say that there is some object, here we just call it $x$, s.t. $A(x)$ is true and there is another, we call that $x$ as well but it could be another object or it could be the same we cannot tell, with which $B(x)$ is true. However on the right hand side we have the statement that there exists an object, we call it $x$ again but it does not have to be the $x$ from the premise, such that both $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are true. And now to whether that is a tautology, I think the comment from zkutch

> Assume A is "x is odd" and B is "x is even", then do you have first?

gives you a pretty good counterexample.

Now to the second. We have the universal quantifier for two objects. I like to imagine that you have an arbitrary element, here $x$, and another arbitrary element, $y$, for which $A(x,y)$ is true. We just gave a collection of elements for which $A$ is true a placeholder with the names or symbols $x,y$. And by explicitely saying for all elements is that statement true, you can put any two arguments in the brackets of $A$ and it would give you a true statement. Having this in mind, the right hand side also has to be true. Because having the same elements as the two arguments surely does not contradict with the premise that any two arbitrary elements can be put into the argument whilst being true.

I hope I helped in getting a better grasp at this topic.